# Create a Class with mandatory and optional properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I am defining a ECMAScript 6 class for my Express web application. It has a mandatory property and a few optional properties. The mandatory field needs to be assigned during class construction while the optional ones don't.

The optional properties only require setting on demand.

```
class Item{

    constructor(mandatoryField) {
        this._mandatoryField = mandatoryField;
        this._optionalField1 = undefined;
        this._optionalField2 = undefined;
        this._optionalField3 = undefined;
    }

    get mandatoryField() {
        return this._mandatoryField;
    }

    set mandatoryField(newVal){
        if(newVal){ 
            this._mandatoryField = newVal;
        }
    }

    get optionalField1() {
        return this._optionalField1;
    }

    set optionalField1(newVal){
        if(newVal){ 
            this._optionalField1 = newVal;
        }
    }

    get optionalField2() {
        return this._optionalField2;
    }

    set optionalField2(newVal){
        if(newVal){ 
            this._optionalField2 = newVal;
        }
    }

    get optionalField3() {
        return this._optionalField3;
    }

    set optionalField3(newVal){
        if(newVal){ 
            this._optionalField3 = newVal;
        }
    }
}

var item1 = new Item("mandVal");
item1.mandatoryField;    // access the mandatory property
item1.optionalField1("optVal");    // set the optional property
item1.optionalField1;    // access the optional property
```

Is there any problem with the declaration as above? How can I enable the optional properties to have default values in the class declaration?

Comment: instead of assining undefined ,  assignt the default values

Comment: Which default value you need to assign?

Comment: What do you need all these setters and getters for? They seem totally superfluous, and ignore assignments of falsy values.

Comment: @Bergi. The setters and getters are needed to assign and access properties after the object is constructed.

Comment: The optional properties are unknown when the class is initialized. They are to be assigned later.

Comment: @alextc No, they are not necessary, you could simply assign to `.mandatoryField`,  `.optionalField1` etc. directly in the constructor.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I know. But how can I get and set the properties after the class is initialized? Do I need getters and setters? Especially for those optional properties, they are set only on demand.

Comment: @alextc You don't need anything, you can assign arbitrary properties to any object you want in JS. It's no different for the optional properties, the only difference is that they got initialised with their default values (`undefined` in your code) instead of from constructor parameters.

Comment: @Bergi But do I need to declare those optional properties in the class constructor? Can you point me an example for the above case?

Comment: @alextc Yes, you should create the properties in the constructor even if their useis optional. You even asked to give them default values, so that's exactly what you should do in the constructor :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify to

```
class Item {
    constructor(mandatoryField) {
        this.mandatoryField = mandatoryField;
        this.optionalField1 = undefined; // this `undefined` is the default value
        this.optionalField2 = undefined;
        this.optionalField3 = undefined;
    }
}

var item1 = new Item("mandVal");
console.log(item1.mandatoryField); // access the mandatory property
console.log(item1.optionalField1); // access an optional property
item1.optionalField1 = "optVal";  // set the optional property
console.log(item1.optionalField1); // access the optional property
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I am pretty new to ECMA6. My code would work too anyway but getters and setters are not just required. According to the mozilla Developer documentation, getter and setter are functions used to create and set peudo-properties.

Answer (score -1):

Create the optional variable before constructor and use as below :

```js
export class Item{

    _optionalField1 = 'some value';
    _optionalField2 = 'some value';
    _optionalField3 = 'some value';
    _mandatoryField = 'some value';
    
        constructor(mandatoryField) {
            this._mandatoryField = mandatoryField;
        }
    
        get mandatoryField() {
            return this._mandatoryField;
        }
    
        set mandatoryField(newVal){
            if(newVal){ 
                this._mandatoryField = newVal;
            }
        }
    
        get optionalField1() {
            return this._optionalField1;
        }
    
        set optionalField1(newVal){
            if(newVal){ 
                this._optionalField1 = newVal;
            }
        }
    
        get optionalField2() {
            return this._optionalField2;
        }
    
        set optionalField2(newVal){
            if(newVal){ 
                this._optionalField2 = newVal;
            }
        }
    
        get optionalField3() {
            return this._optionalField3;
        }
    
        set optionalField3(newVal){
            if(newVal){ 
                this._optionalField3 = newVal;
            }
        }
    }
    
    var item1 = new Item("mandVal");
    item1.mandatoryField;    // access the mandatory property
    item1.optionalField1("optVal");    // set the optional property
    item1.optionalField1;    // access the optional property
```

Comment: Best practice is to assign the variable type also, so that should be added when defining the variables.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid ES8 syntax

Comment: @TarunKhurana I ran your code in jsfiddle but got an error. `Class properties must be methods. Expected '(' but instead saw '='.`

Comment: Did you copied last 4 lines also, if yes, remove that line, those are sample lines for using this class.